# Two circles with the same radius r intersects each other and one passes to the centre of the other.

Tags: geometry

Two circles with the same radius r intersects each other and one passes to the centre of the other.Then the length of the common chord is

can someone help me

I think its answer is r because passes to the centre of the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the length of the common cord will be $\sqrt{3} r$. We are talking about two equilateral triangles with side length r and same base. The distance between the non common vertices of the triangles is the length of the chord. This question can be solved using Pythagoras theorem.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Let the two circles have their centres at $A$ and $C$.

Let them intersect at $D$ and $E$.

Now $AC,AD,AE,CD,CA,CE$ all are radii of those two circles so these must be $r$

By symmetry F is the midpoint of AC so $AF,AC$ must be $r/2$

Also $DE$ and $AC$ must intersect at right angles, so by pythagoreas theorem:
$$AF^2+DF^2=AD^2$$
Solving we get:
$$\implies DF=\sqrt3r/2$$
So, $DE$ must be double of $DF$ $$DE=\sqrt3r$$

Comment: Thank you aditya .I have a doubt that how you are drawing a circle here.I couldn't able to edit the question for some kind like theta,alpha,beta

Comment: go **[here, link](meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)**

Comment: I think your answer is wrong. Solve the value of DF again.

Comment: @Raja thanks...

Comment: yes. df=sqrt(3)